# Variable only updated in second run even with dependency using Graphical Modeler

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I try to use variables for expressions in selecting features etc. I set the variable and also add a dependency in the following block. The protocol of the run also shows that the variable is set before the execution of the next code block.
When I examine the result, the current code block is always executed with the variable value from the previous run.

My test script is very simple. It just sets a field in a test layer. Every time, I execute it, the field is updated with the value from the run before even if the variable is set before updating the field.

I did not find any help with the search function.

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Modell
Group : 
With QGIS : 32207
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Modell(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('testwert', 'Testwert', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=1, maxValue=1000, defaultValue=10))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Erg', 'erg', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Projektvariable setzen
        alg_params = {
            'NAME': 'test2',
            'VALUE': parameters['testwert']
        }
        outputs['ProjektvariableSetzen'] = processing.run('native:setprojectvariable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Feldrechner
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'num',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Fließkommazahl
            'FORMULA': '@test2',
            'INPUT': 'Testlayer_492917bb_3d65_4ee6_b81d_4198bc4a93e3',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Erg']
        }
        outputs['Feldrechner'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Erg'] = outputs['Feldrechner']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Modell'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Modell'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Modell()
```